# Gradio after prediction log a textbox by user input instead of flagging specific predefined label using flagging_options

Tags: python, gradio

After the user clicks the submit button and get the prediction.If the prediction happens to be  incorrect then I want to have a feedback text box where user can provide the text box input.(Its not a classification problem).

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Below is the reproducible code example

```
import gradio as gr

def funct(img_path):
    return "some string"


callback = gr.CSVLogger()

title = "Experiment"
description = "Experiment"

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    
    with gr.Row():
        with gr.Column(scale=2):
            image_in3 = gr.Image(
                label="Image input", type="filepath", elem_id="image-in3", height=300
            )
            

        gr.Markdown(
            """
          ## Output
          """
        )
        with gr.Column(scale=2):
            
            text_out = gr.Text(label="Some text output")

            gr.Markdown(
        """ 
        Enter the correct text output
          """
    )
            correct_lable_user_input  = gr.Text(label="Correct text class")

            with gr.Row():
              btn = gr.Button("Flag as Incorrect")
                
    callback.setup([image_in3, text_out], "flagged_data_captures")

    submit_btn = gr.Button("Submit")
    submit_btn.click(
        fn=funct, inputs=[image_in3], outputs=[text_out]
        
    )

    btn.click(
        
        
        lambda *args: callback.flag(args,flag_option = ["Incorrect"]), [ image_in3,text_out], None,preprocess=False
    )
demo.launch()  # debug=True,share=True
```

I tried clicking the submit button again to but in logs the second text box (feedback) is not getting registered in logs.